# Counting the number of times a letter appears in a String -> Assembly

Tags: c, assembly

Imagine I have a program in C that gives me a string.
For example, "stackoverflow rocks".

Now I want create a function in Assembly that will count, for example, how many times the letter "o" appears in my string.

This function will be called at the C program.

I was thinking to create a program in C that would made me this and then convert it to Assembly trough the flag -s.

[EDIT]
Ok, I did this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int FindChar(char *ptr, char toFind);

int FindChar(char *ptr, char toFind){

    int num;

    for (int i=1; ptr[i]=0; i++)
        if (ptr[i] = toFind){
            num++;
        }

    return(num);
}

int main ( ) {

    char str[]=”stackoverflow rocks”; 
    char tf=”o”; 
    printf(“It appears %d times \n”, FindChar(str,tf));
}
```

What's wrong with my function?

Comment: `ptr[i] = toFind` obvious bug is obvious. Use `==`

Comment: still getting errors...

Comment: Did you actually want an assembly implementation or just a C one?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your alternate double quote characters are causing the errors, plus your initialization of `char tf` should use single quotes, not double quotes, since it is a char not a string.

As [harold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555045/harold) pointed out earlier, the `=` needs to be a `==` so it functions properly as a comparison.

You also don't need to have the additional `i` variable, you can just advance the pointer.
Since you are wanting assembly code anyways, it should make it a bit shorter and also technically be more efficient.

This code fixes the errors and also should be functionally sound:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int FindChar(char *ptr, char toFind);

int FindChar(char *ptr, char toFind){
  int num = 0;
  for ( ; *ptr != '\0'; ++ptr)
    {
      if (*ptr == toFind){
        ++num;
      }
    }
  return(num);
}

int main ( ) {
  char str[]="stackoverflow rocks";
  char tf='o';
  printf("It appears %d times \n", FindChar(str,tf));
}
```